# VB.net, how to select date between 2 date

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, date

How to select date between 2 date using datetimepicker.

I am using

```
SELECT * 
FROM data BETWEEN '"& datetimepicker1.value &"' AND '"& datetimepicker2.value &"'
```

Comment: In what way does this code not work as expected?  What is the resulting SQL statement and what happens when you execute it?

Comment: you forgot something `...from data where date_column between ...`

Comment: convert both dates to a format similar to the one in the database or it will not work. By format, i mean to either seconds or minutes. SQL can't compare values to be in between two strings. it has to be an integer or double or a numerical value

Answer (score 0):

It is very bad practice to concatenate parameters in SQL query. Use special parameter syntax.

Back to you question:
Query should look like:

```
SELECT * from data WHERE someField BETWEEN @Low AND @High
```

And code:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Low", SqlDbType.Int); //set correct type
command.Parameters["@Low"].Value = low;

command.Parameters.Add("@High", SqlDbType.Int);//set correct type
command.Parameters["@High"].Value = high;
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the above answers:

1) You must have the date in the same format of SQL, including seconds (or not). The string must be the same. You may also try 00:00:00 to starttime and 23:59:59 to end-time.

2) You must utilize a conversion from string to date, since your fields are DATE in SQL.

Try:

```
SELECT * from data WHERE someField BETWEEN Convert(datetime, "01/01/1980 00:00:00", 120) AND Convert(datetime, "03/10/2015 23:59:59", 120)
```

Look the '120' above: it´s the SQL format date/time.  Check the available formats to convert date and time in your SQL version.

Comment: So,, if i use datetimepicker,is the syntax like -> Convert(datetime, "datetimepicker1.text", 120) ??

Comment: No. Use "Convert(datetime, datetimepicker1.value, 120)"  to get the value of the control (see the is no "), but remember: if your SQL field contains time, you need to specify time also in your procedure. You would utilize OR datetimepicker.CustomFormat to set something like "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" or even add time like datetimepicker.text & " 00:00:00".